# mysql update one table from another table

Tags: mysql

I try the code below it notwork I guest maybe where clause not orect

```
 update member set member.`status` = 4
     where member.idmember = select DISTINCT activitynote.idmemberref where activitynote.checkkey =4
```

then I try

```
update member, activitynote set member.`status` = 4
 where member.idmember = activitynote.idmemberref
and activitynote.checkkey = 4
```

This code is work but not the thing I want please help

member.idmember  is primary key and  activitynote.idmemberref can be duplicate

Comment: Why the second query is not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then it should solve the problem.

```
update member set member.`status` = 4
where member.idmember IN 
(select DISTINCT activitynote.idmemberref from activitynote where activitynote.checkkey =4)
```

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where activitynote.checkkey =4)' at line 3

Comment: There was no from clause, sorry my mistake.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is not needed.

Comment: UPDATE member SET member.`status` =  '4' WHERE member.idmember IN (
SELECT activitynote.idmemberref
FROM activitynote
WHERE activitynote.checkkey =  '4'
)